# Unable to start PostgreSQL, error looks like its pointing to DB user not found

Tags: postgresql, database

Asking for some assistance with trying to start `postgresql-9.6.2` service using `systemctl` (`systemd`).

I'm installing a monitoring tool that installs an instance of PostgreSQL to support the tool. It creates the postgres user during the install.

I'm running the install as **non-root user** (according to documentation I have the option to run as root or non-root)

Installation was successful, checked the status of `postgresql-9.6.2` and then try to start.

I get this error message:

```
# systemctl status postgresql-9.6.2.service
● postgresql-9.6.2.service - SYSV: Starts and stops the PostgreSQL 9.6.2 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql-9.6.2; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-11-09 01:05:41 GMT; 8min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 9302 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql-9.6.2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 09 01:05:41 sxnda10053.delta.com systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Starts and stops the PostgreSQL 9.6.2 database server...
Nov 09 01:05:41 10053.com postgresql-9.6.2[9302]: Starting PostgreSQL 9.6.2:
Nov 09 01:05:41 10053.com postgresql-9.6.2[9302]: su: user DB_SERVICE_USER does not exist
Nov 09 01:05:41 10053.com postgresql-9.6.2[9302]: PostgreSQL 9.6.2 did not start in a timely fashion, please see DB_INSTALL_DIR/pg_log/startup.log for details
Nov 09 01:05:41 10053.com systemd[1]: postgresql-9.6.2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 09 01:05:41 10053.com systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Starts and stops the PostgreSQL 9.6.2 database server.
Nov 09 01:05:41 10053.com systemd[1]: Unit postgresql-9.6.2.service entered failed state.
Nov 09 01:05:41 10053.com systemd[1]: postgresql-9.6.2.service failed.
[root@10053 xdg]# systemctl start postgresql-9.6.2.service
Job for postgresql-9.6.2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status postgresql-9.6.2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Any assistance would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: On which Linux distro is that? My servers have long had native systemd startup scripts for all shipped services, so this looks a bit like an unsupported thing to me ... But doesn't have to be bad. How did your exactly install PostgreSQL on your machine?

Comment: This is redhat 7.9
PostgreSQL was installed through an Enterprise Monitoring tool

Comment: ah that's interesting; I would have expected that to use the same (or very similar) startup scripts as Fedora. anyway, after having read the log twice: it *literally* tries to change to a user called `DB_SERVICE_USER`. So somewhere in the startup script, the installer failed to replace that with the right name. maybe a quick `grep -R DB_SERVICE_USER /etc` might reveal the culprit?